# Compiling mptfc kernel module for CentOS 7 -- insmod returns "invalid parameters"

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, centos7, kernel-module

I'm trying to compile the *mptfc* driver for a CentOS 7 box. We have some legacy hardware that we need to support on CentOS 7 for dependency reasons.

*mptfc* was included in CentOS 6, but in CentOS 7 they decided to not include it in the kernel any more. (source: [Redhat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/6.9_technical_notes/chap-red_hat_enterprise_linux-6.9_technical_notes-deprecated_functionality))

I noticed that *elrepo* created a RPM for the driver (from this [article](http://lists.elrepo.org/pipermail/elrepo/2017-May/003572.html)), but I had to dig for it. Eventually found it in some mirrors that provided archive capabilities, but the computer would not finish booting the kernel. Unfortunately, I don't have that output to display, but it wasn't pretty. Lots of error messages.

Because I can not use CentOS 6, I decided the next choice was to compile the kernel module myself. I have never done that, so I am running into a few issues.

First, I downloaded the headers for the kernel I am running (3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64) using:

```
yum install linux-headers
```

Then I downloaded the source code on a different machine for Linux 3.10 from [Github](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/releases/tag/v3.10). I copied the `drivers/message/fusion` directory from the source code to the machine I am compiling and put it in my home folder. I modified the Makefile to look like:

```
...
obj-$(CONFIG_FUSION_SPI)        += mptbase.o mptscsih.o mptspi.o
obj-m           += mptbase.o mptscsih.o mptfc.o
obj-m   += mptbase.o mptscsih.o mptsas.o
obj-$(CONFIG_FUSION_CTL)        += mptctl.o
obj-$(CONFIG_FUSION_LAN)        += mptlan.o

KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)
default:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
```

Then I ran `make`. It compiles fine, but when I try to do the following:

```
insmod mptfc.ko
```

I get the following:

```
[root@host fusion]# insmod mptfc.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module mptfc.ko: Invalid parameters
```

And dmesg returns:

```
[root@host fusion]# dmesg | tail
[184711.751960] mptfc: disagrees about version of symbol mptscsih_qcmd
[184711.751970] mptfc: Unknown symbol mptscsih_qcmd (err -22)
```

I've never compiled kernel modules before, so I'm not sure where to start debugging this.

My end goal is to get the legacy pci card that uses mptfc working. If there is a better way to get the driver into the kernel, and working, that works as well.